# Single Spring based ehcache manager for multiple ehcache.xml files in a multi module project

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I have a multi module project with all the modules defining their cache configurations in their own ehcache.xml. 
This use case is addressed by the now unmaintained "ehcache-spring-annotations" project through a configuration like this:

```
    <ehcache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" create-missing-caches="true"/>

    <bean id="ehCacheManager" class="net.sf.itcb.addons.cachemanager.ItcbEhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
      <property name="configLocations" value="classpath*:ehcache.xml"/>
      <property name="shared" value="true"/>
    </bean>
```

I tried something similar in Spring's Cache Abstraction.

```
    <cache:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="cacheManager"
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" 
      p:cache-manager-ref="ehcache"/>

    <bean id="ehcache"
      class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean"      
      p:config-location="classpath*:ehcache.xml"/>
```

However, I ran into this exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  class path resource [classpath*:ehcache.xml] cannot be opened because
  it does not exist
```

Can someone please explain what is the correct way to configure Spring's Cache Abstraction for EhCache in a multi module project?

Comment: Raised this as an [issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14884) in Spring project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, we moved away from ehcache.xml and started using Java based configuration for our caches which solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple `CacheManagers` in single Spring context, you will have to define multiple beans and add qualifiers to them to be able to differentiate them based on some context.

So there is nothing specific to caching here, it is the classical multiple beans of the same type in Spring.

Comment: Hi @Louis Jacomet, thanks for your suggestion. I have nearly 20+ modules and all of them have a ehcache.xml file. The current solution I use merges all those ehcache.xml files into a single input stream and create a single cache manager. I was wondering whether that's supported by Spring out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Did this by creating the cache managers in different ways as spring doesn't allow two EhCacheManagerFactoryBean in the context and the configlocation is set soon after bean creation, so cannot be updated.

```
@Bean("ehCacheManager1")
fun EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager1(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean: CacheManager): EhCacheCacheManager =
    EhCacheCacheManager(ehCacheManagerFactoryBean)

@Bean("ehCacheManagerFactoryBean")
public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean() {
  EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();
  cacheManagerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("ehcache1.xml"));
  cacheManagerFactoryBean.setShared(true);
  return cacheManagerFactoryBean;
}

@Bean("ehCacheManager2")
@Primary
fun ehCacheManager2(): EhCacheCacheManager {
  val configLocation = cacheProperties().resolveConfigLocation(ClassPathResource("ehcache.xml"))
  return EhCacheCacheManager(CacheManager.create(configLocation.url))
}

@Bean
fun cacheProperties() = CacheProperties()
```